# Difference between declaring methods within a class or using the class prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference when we declare our methods within a class

```
class Foo {
   ...
   doSomething(){
     ...
   }
}
```

or directly to the class prototype?

```
class Foo {
    ...
}

Foo.prototype.doSomething = function(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is a JavaScript question and has nothing to do with React directly

Comment: Thanks, edited just now

Comment: we do `Foo.prototype.doSomething = function(){...}` only when declared through `function constructor` not class

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is that one style is readable and the other is not :-) For all normal purposes, they behave the same.

However, they do differ in details:

- the assigned method is anonymous, the defined method has a `.name`
- the assigned `function` has a `.prototype` and is constructible, the defined method doesn't
- the assigned method is enumerable, the defined method is not
- the assigned method cannot use the `super` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Some restrictions apply when defined as *method* as part of the `class` definition:

- It cannot be an arrow function
- It cannot serve as a constructor

Those restrictions do not apply when using the `.prototype.doSomething =` notation.

Those restrictions do not hold either with the newer [field declaration feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) (experimental, in stage 3 at the time of writing):

One can assign an arrow function to such a field, or a `function`. In the latter case, that function can serve as a constructor.

However, a function assigned to an instance field is not a *prototype* method, but an instance member, and so it would not exactly correspond to what you would do with the `.prototype` alternative in your question.

Comment: Actually you can do arrow functions ( `doSomething = () => ... `)

Comment: As mentioned, your first point is incorrect as per the [istance field](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-fields/) proposal. Although then it is an *instance method* rather than a method.
So then with two instances `f1` and `f2` it does not hold that `f1.doSomething === f2.doSomething` like it would have with methods on the prototype.

Comment: Thank you both, I have added this information & qualified this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `class` code transpiled to ES < 6 you'll see it is similar but [quite different](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0MBN4GV4FsBTAFwAsBLAOwHMAKASjQ2eHkonhEIDoR46A5BQH10GAL6pxQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.3.3).

In a nutshell class will do this (pseudocode):

```
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'doSomething', doSomething)
```